# Add 12 hours to time.now in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding 12 hours to the current time. but the current time is displayed in the text box, what is wrong with the code

```
 DateTime expiresAt = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
 txt_ExpiresBy.Text = expiresAt.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you are adding 12 hours and you don't see the difference between X AM and X PM?
Try using `HH` (hour in 24 hours format) instead of `hh` (hour in 12 hours format) in the format string, or adding the AM/PM indicator `tt`:

```
// 24 hours format
expiresAt.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// 12 hours + am/pm
expiresAt.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for a complete reference.

Comment: Note that there's no need for these to be verbatim string literals, either.